# Trying to get the average, standard deviation and new row count after scrubbing data

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm using Advantage Works 2012 and I'm scrubbing the data to get rid of outliers for order qty. The max & min looks like its working, but the new standard deviation doesn't appear to work and when I do a new count on OrderQty I get a ridiculous number that is higher than the orig count.  I did the new standard deviation, but it doesn't appear to be right. It's a little bit off.

I added the new count after I was done with all the CTE's. but the number is higher than the original count. It looks like it is 3X higher than the original row count.

```
WITH rawdata 
     AS (SELECT sod.[salesorderid], 
                [orderqty], 
                [purchaseordernumber] 
         FROM   [AdventureWorks2012].[Sales].[salesorderdetail]sod 
                JOIN [Sales].[salesorderheader] soh 
                  ON sod.salesorderid = soh.salesorderid), 
     stats 
     AS (SELECT [salesorderid], 
                Avg([orderqty])   Avg_qty, 
                Sum([orderqty])   sum_qty, 
                Stdevp([orderqty])STDDev_Qty, 
                Min([orderqty])   Min_Qty, 
                Max([orderqty])   Max_Qty, 
                Count(*)          ctrows 

         FROM   [Sales].[salesorderdetail] 
         GROUP  BY [salesorderid]), 
     diff 
     AS (SELECT salesorderid, 
                Round(( avg_qty - stddev_qty ), 2) AS NegDiff, 
                Round(( avg_qty + stddev_qty ), 2) AS PosDiff 
         FROM   stats), 
     scrubed 
     AS (SELECT st.salesorderid, 
                r.orderqty, 
                d.negdiff, 
                d.posdiff 
         FROM   stats st 
                INNER JOIN diff d 
                        ON st.salesorderid = d.salesorderid 
                JOIN rawdata r 
                  ON st.salesorderid = r.salesorderid 
         WHERE  r.[orderqty] > st.avg_qty - stddev_qty 
                AND r.[orderqty] < st.avg_qty + stddev_qty 
         GROUP  BY st.salesorderid, 
                   r.[orderqty], 
                   d.negdiff, 
                   d.posdiff) 
SELECT r.[salesorderid], 
       ctrows                        AS rawct, 
       --  r.[purchaseordernumber],  
       st.avg_qty                    AS oldAvgQty, 
       sum_qty                       AS sumQty, 
       Round(st.stddev_qty, 2)       AS Old_StdDevQty, 
       Round(st.min_qty, 2)          AS Min_Qty, 
       Round(st.max_qty, 2)          AS Max_Qty, 
       Round(Avg(sc.orderqty), 4)    AS NewAvgQty, 
       Round(Stdevp(sc.orderqty), 4) AS NewStdDevQty, 
       Min(sc.orderqty)              AS newMin, 
       Max(sc.orderqty)              AS NewMax, 
       negdiff                       AS LowerLimit, 
       posdiff                       AS HigherLimit 
FROM   rawdata r 
       LEFT JOIN scrubed sc 
              ON r.salesorderid = sc.salesorderid 
       JOIN stats st 
         ON sc.salesorderid = st.salesorderid 
GROUP  BY r.salesorderid, 
          -- r.[purchaseordernumber],  
          st.avg_qty, 
          sum_qty, 
          st.stddev_qty, 
          st.max_qty, 
          st.min_qty, 
          ctrows, 
          negdiff, 
          posdiff 
ORDER  BY 1
```

I expect to get the right row count and the right standard deviation of the data after its scrubbed.

Comment: "AdventureWorks", not "Advantage Works". And it is a little concerning that you mix 3 and 2 part names for your tables. This implies you are using both your "custom" copy of the standard AdventureWorks database as well as the standard one. The short answer is that you need to verify the correctness of each CTE before you attempt to put it all together and validate.

Comment: it is AdventureWorks2012.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @STD DECIMAL(5,2)

set @std = 2.0;
With rawdata as 
(SELECT [salesorderid], 
                Avg([orderqty])   Avg_qty, 
                round(Stdevp([orderqty]),2) STDDev_Qty, 
                Min([orderqty])   Min_Qty, 
                Max([orderqty])   Max_Qty, 
                Count(*)          ctrows, 
                Sum(orderqty)     AS Ordqty_sum,
                Avg([orderqty]) - @STD as LowerLmt,
                Avg([orderqty]) + @STD as HigherLmt


         FROM   [Sales].[salesorderdetail] 
         --Where [salesorderid] = 53621
         GROUP  BY [salesorderid]    ),

         scrubed as(


         select         sod.SalesOrderID,
                        sod.orderqty


         FROM 

         [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]sod inner join rawdata c on sod.SalesOrderID=c.SalesOrderID
         Where 
         --sod.salesorderid = 53621 and 
         sod.orderqty between c.LowerLmt and c.HigherLmt )


         select 
                c.salesorderid,
                c.ctrows oldCtrows,
                Avg_qty oldAvg,
                STDDev_Qty oldStd,
                Min_Qty oldMin,
                Max_Qty oldMax,
                count(s.SalesOrderID)newct , 
                avg(orderqty)newAvg, 
                min(orderqty)NewMin, 
                max(orderqty)NewMax, 
                round(stdevp(orderqty),3)newSTD,
                c.LowerLmt,
                c.HigherLmt



         from scrubed s join  rawdata c on s.salesorderid= c.SalesOrderID
         Where  c.ctrows > 20
         group by 
                c.salesorderid,
                c.ctrows,
                c.Avg_qty ,
                c.STDDev_Qty ,
                c.Min_Qty ,
                c.Max_Qty ,
                c.LowerLmt,
                c.HigherLmt
```